# Is there a cleaner way to combine std::string into std::vector<char>?

Tags: c++, string, insert, std, stdvector

I have some code that combines various elements into a buffer. My code looks something like this:

```
static void CreatePacket(const std::string& source, const std::string id, const std::string payload, std::vector<char>& buffer)
{
    buffer.resize(source.size() + id.size() + payload.size());
    std::vector<char>::iterator bufferDest = buffer.begin();

    // Start the message
    char MessageStart = '$';
    *bufferDest = MessageStart;
    ++bufferDest;

    // Copy the message source
    std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), bufferDest);
    bufferDest += source.size();

    // Copy the message id
    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), bufferDest);
    bufferDest += id.size();
}
```

That method is called as follows:

```
std::vector<char> buffer;

std::string source = "AB";
std::string id = "CDE";
std::string payload = "payload";

CreatePacket(source, id, payload, buffer);
```

I'm still a bit green on the `std` way of doing things, but my implementation feels a bit clunky (specifically, having to explicitly increment the `bufferDest` after each copy). Is there a cleaner way to do this?

My compiler doesn't support C++11 if that makes a difference.

Comment: you do not need to explicitly increment the `bufferDest`, `std::copy` return that to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a proper [**`vector::insert()`** overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to append the content of a `string` at the end of the `vector` (no need to complicate the code using `std::copy` or `std::back_inserter` as showed in other answers), e.g.:

```
buffer.insert(buffer.end(), source.begin(), source.end());
```

So your function would look like this:

```
void CreatePacket(const std::string& source, 
                  const std::string& id, 
                  const std::string& payload, 
                  std::vector<char>& buffer)
{
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.reserve(source.size() + id.size() + payload.size() + 1);

    buffer.push_back('$');

    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), source.begin(),  source.end() );
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), id.begin(),      id.end()     );
    buffer.insert(buffer.end(), payload.begin(), payload.end());
}
```

Comment: To the layman, this doesn't look very different to Danh's answer. Is there any advantage in doing it this way?

Comment: @JonCage: This _is_ different from that answer, as Danh uses `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter`, instead I just use `std::vector::insert`, so this code is simpler.

Comment: @MrC64 - I hadn't intending to suggest they were the same, just to an STL newbie, they look about as complex as each other. I was just interested as to why one might choose one vs the other. After staring at the two for a while I can see yours does look a little easier to see what the intention is.

Comment: @JonCage: Exactly. I also posted a reply to a comment of yours in Danh's answer. It doesn't make sense to `#include <algorithm>` and `<iterator>` for `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter`, and potentially adding more overhead with those functions, if there's already a direct method inside `std::vector` that can do the same operations, and potentially in a better faster more optimized way.

Comment: Upvoted! at the time of writing, I was under effect of the question so I can't think about this solution

Answer (score 8):

I think this is much clearer.

```
void CreatePacket(const std::string& source, const std::string& id, const std::string& payload, std::vector<char>& buffer)
{
    buffer.clear();
    buffer.reserve(source.size() + id.size() + payload.size() + 1);

    buffer.push_back('$');

    std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(buffer));
    std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), std::back_inserter(buffer));
    std::copy(payload.begin(), payload.end(), std::back_inserter(buffer));
}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly the sort of thing I had in mind :-)

Comment: @JonCage: You can actually simplify your code further: the `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter` are not necessary, unless I'm missing something. You can just use `std::vector::insert`, as showed in my other answer.

Comment: @Mr.C64 - What are the advantages of doing your suggestion vs this? They both look like fairly viable solutions to me. Both look better than my code ;-)

Comment: @JonCage: In my suggested way, I just use a `std::vector`'s method (i.e. `std::vector::insert`), instead of complexifying code with _external_ functions like `std::copy` from `<algorithm>` or `std::back_inserter` from `<iterator>`. If `std::vector` has already a direct method to do that, why making the code more complex adding more layers of abstractions with external stuff? Moreover, I think that `vector::insert` can produce better more optimized code, as it's a method _of_ `vector`, so it can do some optimizations knowing the vector's internal mechanics.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense to me too.

Answer (score 2):

It is almost clean except that you can use return value from `std::copy` and thus get rid of explicit increment of `bufferDest`:

```
static void CreatePacket(const std::string& source, const std::string id, const std::string payload, std::vector<char>& buffer)
{
    buffer.resize(source.size() + id.size() + payload.size());
    std::vector<char>::iterator bufferDest = buffer.begin();

    // Start the message
    char MessageStart = '$';
    *bufferDest = MessageStart;
    ++bufferDest;

    // Copy the message source
    bufferDest = std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), bufferDest);

    // Copy the message id
    bufferDest= std::copy(id.begin(), id.end(), bufferDest);
}
```